# Cannot access Adsense funds after switching to third-party partnership program

Tags: google-adsense

I had a Google Adsense partnership with $80 in it, but then switched to a different partnership and now can't get my money.

When I first started YouTube, I joined the Adsense partnership program. After gaining $80 in my Adsense account, I got an offer to join a third party partnership program called Zoomin.tv. I accepted, and it is paying me monthly now.

The problem is that my Adsense account still has the $80 in it, and is not gaining more cash. The Zoomin.tv money is going directly to my PayPal. The payment threshold in Adsense is $100, and you can't make it lower. Therefore, my money is stuck in Adsense and I'd love a solution that allows me to access my money.

Comment: I now see that responses here will be automatically emailed to me, so go ahead and leave a comment here if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Find a way to use your AdSense account and get more money to get up to the threshold.

Eg start a blog, and put AdSense on it.   (but do make sure that you're meeting AdSense's terms and conditions)